# Connected dominating set in bipartite graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G$ a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) with two disjoint set of vertices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.

Denote $n_a:=|\mathbf{A}|$, $n_b:=|\mathbf{B}|$. Suppose the following conditions hold:

- $\Theta(1)<n_b<\Theta(n_a)$.
- $\Theta(1)<\min\mathrm{deg}(\mathbf{B})<\max\mathrm{deg}(\mathbf{B})<\Theta(n_a)$.
- The set $\mathbf{B}$ is a dominating set, i.e., any vertex $A_i \in \mathbf{A}$ is connected to $\mathbf{B}$.
- There are $\Theta(n_a)$ vertices in $\mathbf{A}$ that are connected to at least $2$ vertices in $\mathbf{B}$.

My question is:

- Can we construct a [connected dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_dominating_set) $\mathbf{D}$ such that $|\mathbf{A}\cup \mathbf{B} \backslash \mathbf{D}| = \Theta(n_a)$ ?

Here, $\Theta$ is the [Big-theta notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent) in computational complexity.

Any proof, counter-example, or proof ideas are welcomed.